# Surjectivity of pushforward on Chow rings for stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, intersection-theory

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a proper morphism of smooth Deligne-Mumford stacks of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$ that is birational, but not flat. The coarse spaces of $X$ and $Y$ are both not smooth. Is proper pushforward $f_*:A^*(X)_{\mathbb{Q}}\rightarrow A^*(Y)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is surjective?

The way I want to prove a statement like this is using a projection formula argument on the coarse spaces, but I don't have a reasonable way to define pullback in the absence of flatness and the fact that the coarse spaces aren't smooth. Another idea is to take a cycle on $Y$ and try to move it out of the exceptional locus, take its preimage, and then push that forward, but I don't know if there is a moving lemma on stacks. I can't apply it on the coarse space because the coarse space of $Y$ is not regular. Can I remedy one of these arguments by working on the level of the stack instead of the coarse space?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the settings, but if $Y'\to Y$ is an etale cover by a scheme, then the projection formula shows that $A^*(Y')_{\mathbb{Q}}\to A^*(Y)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is surjective so pulling back to $Y'$ and using base-change reduces the problem to the case of schemes, isn't it?

Comment: More precisely rational Chow groups I think satisfy Galois descent and since invariants are exact functor over the rationals you can reduce to schemes.

Comment: @S.carmeli  Rational Chow groups do not satisfy "Galois descent", if by that you mean descent for etale covers.  Consider the standard open affine cover of projective space by affine spaces.  Regarding your first comment, few Deligne-Mumford stacks admit an etale cover that is also *finite*, which is what you would need to apply your argument.  Instead, use duality between $A^*_{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $A_{*,\mathbb{Q}}$ on smooth, proper, Deligne-Mumford stacks, then pass to the coarse moduli spaces (singular, but still have pushforward on $A_{*,\mathbb{Q}}$ surjective).

Comment: @jason Starr you are absolutely right thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help.